# Signing .net assemblies without sharing certificate with dev team

Tags: .net, visual-studio, code-signing

I'm trying to understand a particular workflow for our team. We got our Godaddy code signing cert in spc form yesterday. We work in a secure environment and we don't want to share the cert with all developers.

Is it possible we just install this on the build machine and not share it with all development machines?

I'm basically just trying to find a way to sign our assemblies and not have everything break for developers desktops.

Advice?

TIA.

Comment: Learn about strong assembly and executable signature. They are two different things and you should be specific on which you are talking about.

Comment: Code-signing has nothing to do with strong names and does not in any way affect or interest the devs.  You do it right after you built your final shipping build before you give it to customers.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i'm taking about signing each assembly by going  into the project properties, signing tab, and checking "Sign the Assembly".

Ultimately, signing with a cert from the cert store on just the build machine would be best.

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for delay signing.

Check the Delay Sign checkbox in Project Properties, then run `sn -vR` on the developer desktops to skip verification for the project.
 Alternatively, use Roslyn's [FakeSign trick](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Tools/Source/FakeSign/Program.cs).

Comment: Yes, delay signing is a common approach.